# Jquery-ui tabs. Per tab caching

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I read here that the caching strategy of the tabs can be achieved by setting the "cache.tabs" property of the anchor to true/false. When I do this thing from javascript debugger (in chrome Ctrl+Shift+J) it works ok, but when I put the cod into the header of the page it doesn't work. When I put the javascript inline into the page it even does not load the tab. What i am doing wrong ? Here is the code :

```
jQuery(function() { $("a:contains('SearchedAnchor')").data('cache.tabs', true);});
```

Answer (score 0):

When putting in your page, have you added the fact that the document needs to be loaded before doing this?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(function() { $("a:contains('SearchedAnchor')").data('cache.tabs', true);});
}
```

Comment: 'jQuery(document).ready(function() {' and 'jQuery(function() {' have identical behavior, i tried also adding the ready instruction, that changes nothing